# Dynamics CRM 2011: Extended lookup for a field in "Create New" form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have the following scenario:

A user wants to create a new record of entity CustomEntity1. One of the fields on the "Create New" form is a reference to the entity of type CustomEntity2.

Now, there is a built in lookup where thety can search by name, or filter the options to a predefined view. This doesn't help, because the user needs to get the name (or names) of CustomEntity2 which satisfies a set of criteria based on the fields in CustomEntity2.

Is there a way to incorporate this in "Create New" form for CustomEntity1?

And the question again, a bit less abstract:

The user needs to create a new record of type **CustomerAccount**. In doing this he/she needs to fill a field called **Group**. This should be looked up in a list of existing **groups**, based on several criteria - **Type**, **Region**, **Budget** and so on. Is there a way for the user to enter this criteria while creating the new record, and not go separately to the list of Groups and run a report to find the candidates?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`addCustomView` method of the lookup control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_addCustomView) to filter the options based on the `fetchXML` and `layoutXML` that you provide.

One way to supply the right conditions to your custom `fetchXML` is to duplicate the `Type`, `Region`, and `Budget` fields in the `CustomerAccount` form, so that when the lookup dialog is opened, it filters the existing `Groups` based on the values you've selected in the `CustomerAccount` form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I was aware of this possibility however I was hoping there is a solution that doesn't involve modifying my **CustomerAccount** entity (and my understanding is that if I have these fields on **CustomerAccount** form I need to have them in the entity also).
Ideally I would like to have the **Group** selection logic decoupled from the downstream usage by relevant entities.

Comment: @CxDoo In this case, an alternative approach is to create a `webresource` housed in an IFRAME that references the selections relevant to `Group` that you need to access. Outside of duplicating those attributes to the `CustomerAccount` entity, this is the only other way I can think of to present these selections to the user in the `CustomerAccount` form.